# fhir.js - how to pass Oauth token in the search query in nodejs app

Tags: hl7-fhir, dstu2-fhir, hapi-fhir

I have a nodejs app that connects to an FHIR server and queries patient data. I am not sure how do I pass the Oauth2 token to the getPatient function.
I am using fhir.js node library for the application.

```js
var Fhir = require('fhir.js');
var user = require('user.js);

function getPatient(response){
 return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
 var patientid = 123456;
  var Oauth2Token = user.token;
 
 // Create fhir instance
 var fhir = Fhir({

     baseUrl: process.env.baseUrl,

 });
 
 // Execute the search
 fhir.search({
 
     type: 'Patient', 
     query: {id: patientid}
 
     })
 
     .then(function(response){
     //manipulate your data here.
     var data = response.data.entry[0].resource;
     console.log("FHIR Data :",data);
     resolve(data);
     })
     .catch(function(error){
         //Error responses
         if (error.status){
             console.log('Error', error.status);
             reject(error);
         }
 
         //Errors
         if (error.message){
             console.log('Error', error.message);
             reject(error);
         }
     });
 
 });
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at the [Readme](https://github.com/FHIR/fhir.js/blob/master/README.md#create-instance-of-the-fhir-client):

```
 var fhir = Fhir({

     baseUrl: process.env.baseUrl,
     auth: {
       bearer: 'YOURTOKEN'
     }

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try putting the patientId in quotes?
`var patientid = "123456";`